# VSCode Terminal drops output from AWS CLI

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-cli, amazon-elb

While running some AWS CLI commands recently via Powershell in the VSCode terminal, I noticed it completely drops/doesn't render all the output. Specifically I do something like:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers
```

This will show anywhere from 14 to 122 lines of output before returning to the prompt. Whereas if I take the same command and run it in a standalone instance of Powershell it will print all 971 lines.

**Notes:**

- I'm using the same powershell .exe configured in VSCode's terminal as I ran standalone:

  ```
  "powershell.powerShellExePath": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
  ```
- Piping the output to a file from within the VSCode terminal will also successfully save all 971 lines.
- This happens on a fresh terminal window with no previous buffered lines.
- Powershell PSVersion: 5.1.16299.98
- VSCode Version: 1.19.1
- Windows 10

**Update:**
An issue has been filed on GitHub ([Original Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42847)), and is being looked at with a number of other Windows terminal issues here:

[Windows terminal issues caused by winpty](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45693)

I will update and answer this question with whatever resolution comes from the VS Code team when the time comes.

Comment: I've used AWS in Code and can't say I've seen that but I have not used it in the last version. First guess you might try increasing your scrollback, defaults to 1000, but I have mine set to 5k. `"terminal.integrated.scrollback": 5000`

Comment: Unfortunately this happens sometimes having printed only 14 lines or less, in a brand new console window with a much higher than normal scroll buffer.

Comment: If it does not do the same thing to you in a normal PowerShell console all you can do is submit an issue to VS Code.